# Correct way of retrieving input text value in jQuery 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is how I used to get the input text value prior to jQuery 1.9.1

```
<input type="text" id="input_text_Id" 

...

$("#input_text_Id").attr('value')
```

It no longer works when I upgraded my jQuery version to 1.9.1, so apparently it's been deprecated.

What are my other options?

I'm also curious, what are the reasons jQuery creators keep removing features that works without any issues? I'm assuming security vulnerability might be one of them.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't the following work:

```
$("#input_text_Id").val();
```

It's what I've always used.

Here's the [documentation on val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: For some unknown reason, it didn't. It throws an undefined error.

Comment: @l46kok: Post the full error message.

Comment: Did you close your `input` element or was your question code just a quick and dirty copy and paste? What's the full error message?

Comment: @l46kok - "undefined error"? Are you sure that jquery javascript file has actually loaded?

Comment: I just found out that the code works correctly on Chrome but not on IE 10. ????????

Comment: Internet Explorer giving headache problems since memorable times =\

Comment: @l46kok can you post what all this is wrapped in? Is it wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function() {...})()` or equivalent anonymous function?

Answer (score 1):

`attr("value")` (and the native `getAttribute("value")`) return the *attribute*.

`val()` (and the native `value`) return the *property*.

The important difference here is that the attribute is essentially the "default value", whereas the property is the current one.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6vCwY/) is a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use retrieve value property via [val() function](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're after the current value of the input element. then just use `.val()`:

```
$("#input_text_Id").val();
```

`.attr('value')` returns the value of the `value` attribute (which doesn't change when you type text), not the `.value` property (which does change).

[Type in this textbox](http://jsfiddle.net/fZSRZ/) and look in your console to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#input_text_Id').val();`

As to why the jQuery team chose to remove the method you used to use, I don't know. I suspect this method was closed off because getting the value from an input isn't really derived from its "value" attribute. I believe getting the input's actual value is pulled from the input's "value" property in the DOM.